# What does .L.str mean in objcopy command?

Tags: build, android-ndk, elf, objcopy

I am reading my build scripts of my project and found a place where it is written the following command

`objcopy --redefine-sym =.L.str before.a after.a`

Could somebody please explain me what does `.L.str` mean here?

Comment: It's just a symbol name. But where is the old symbol name that's supposed to go before the `=`? Is that the exact command you are running?

Comment: @Michael, it seems they want to remove empty symbols and added this snippet to build scripts.

If it is symbol, could you please tell me what this corresponds to.